# Transpose dataframe in R multiple columns

Tags: r, reshape, transpose, reshape2

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
x <- c('Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Sue', 'Sue', 'Sue')
y <- c(100, 200, 150, 40, 50, 30)
z <- c(5, 6, 4, 3, 4, 4)
num <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)

df <- data.frame(x,y,z,num)
```

And I need to transpose this so that i have a row for Jim and a row for Sue, with the values of y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3.

I know how to do this with `data.table::dcast` but the Linux server I'm using is having difficulty loading this package.  Therefore, I am trying to do it with the `reshape` package or even just the `reshape()` function, but running into difficulty.

```
# This gives the desired result
df1 <- data.table::dcast(setDT(df), x ~ num, value.var=c('y', 'z'))

# Trying to figure out what I'm missing here...
df2 <- reshape::cast(df, num ~ x, value = c('y', 'z'))
```

Comment: Using `reshape` from base R: `reshape(df, idvar = 'x', direction = 'wide', timevar = 'num')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly, I don't know `data.table` all that well and `reshape2` has some funky syntax (in my opinion, at least) that takes some time to learn.

I had to `melt()` your data frame into a better format, then use `dcast()` to get the final output.

```
library(reshape2)

> df %>%
+   melt(id.vars = c("x", "num"), measure.vars = c("y", "z")) %>%
+   dcast(x ~ paste0(.$variable, .$num), value.var = "value")
    x  y1  y2  y3 z1 z2 z3
1 Jim 100 200 150  5  6  4
2 Sue  40  50  30  3  4  4
```

Comment: @denis, not really sure of the point of your comment when the OP already knows how to use `data.table::dcast` (and the approach isn't similar at all since there's no need to create a longer table before transforming it to a wide table).

Answer (score 1):

Well maybe next time use `aggregate` from base r:

```
 aggregate(.~x,df[-4],I)
    x y.1 y.2 y.3 z.1 z.2 z.3
1 Jim 100 200 150   5   6   4
2 Sue  40  50  30   3   4   4
```

Comment: I think many people would be confused by the `str` of this output. Can be resolved with a `do.call(data.frame, aggregate(...))`.